# laravel ORM multiple values

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm

I'm working on learning a bit about laravel, and I'm a little unsure of what the proper route is for the following:

I want to have a user dashboard that shows the user's total messages, divided up by the read / unread messages, as well as a task list showing upcoming tasks as well as overdue tasks.

Right now the way I'm looking at doing this is setting these values in the controller:

```
// the user index controller function
public function getIndex()
{
    $read = Message::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('read', '=', 1);
    $unread = Message::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
            ->where('read', '=', 0);
    // etc

    return View::make('user.index');
}
```

This seems really a bit pointless and repetitive. Is there a way to return the total `messages` result to the view and then split them up by read / unread there, or is it smarter to create functions in the model that will return these number directly? Or maybe I'm totally missing the right way?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most convenient way would be creating simple relations:

```
// User
public function messages()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Message');
}

public function unreadMessages()
{
  return $this->messages()->where('read', 0);
}

// or using filter method and accessor
public function getUnreadMessagesAttribute()
{
  return $this->messages->filter(function ($message) {
     return $message->read == 0;
  });
}

public function readMessages()
{
  return $this->messages()->where('read', 1);
}

public function tasks()
{
  return $this->hasMany('Task');
}

public function todoTasks()
{
  // for example:
  return $this->tasks()->where('deadline', '>', Carbon::now())->where('done', 0);
}

public function overdueTasks()
{
  return $this->tasks()->where('deadline', '<', Carbon::now())->where('done', 0);
}
```

Then you can simply use this:

```
Auth::user()->overdueTasks;
Auth::user()->unreadMessages;
```

2nd solution using `filter` on the collection has one advantage = it saves the DB query.

Answer (score 0):

```
$messages = Message::where('user_id', Auth::id())->get()->groupBy('read');

// ['0' => [...models...], '1' => [...models...]]

return View::make('user.index', [
    'messages' => [
        'unread' => array_get($messages, '0', []),
        'read' => array_get($messages, '1', []),
    ],
]);
```

Comment: @user3055285 - Use 4.2 - `groupBy` was added in 4.2

Answer (score 0):

```
$messages = Message::where('user_id', '=', Auth::user()->id)
                ->get(array(
                        '*',
                        DB::raw('IF(read = '1', 1, 0) AS is_read'),
                    ));
```

> All the read messages will have a key of is_read set to 1 and unread will have a key set to 0